# How to display "create shortcut" dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp

is there a way how to run the "create shortcut" dialog programatically ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Quite a smorgasbord of languages you have there.  Pick one.

Comment: The programming language is not necessary for me. I've added them, because not everyone watches "windows" or "winapi" tags, which are best fitting for this topis and I really need to know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe you are looking for this:

```
rundll32.exe appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere C:\path\to\my\folder
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [typepad.com](https://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0128776ff992970c-pi))</sub>

Comment: In addition, it is apparently undcumented, so I wouldn't recommend it. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vistacompatteam/archive/2006/10/20/rundll32-exe-appwiz-cpl-newlinkhere-is-back.aspx

Comment: It works on Win 7 32 & 64 by my quick testing. You have to pass in a path to a folder that exists - don't include a file name.

Comment: `dir := 'C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop';ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'rundll32', PChar('appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere ' + dir), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)` doesn't do anything. I suspect the spaces are the problem.

Comment: I've retagged this question. I need this for a very specific task only on Windows XP and there it works.

Comment: Andreas that will get you the 32 bit rundll32 which I don't think you want. Just fire it off from the Windows Run dialog. Remember to put your folder name in quotes!

Comment: @David: Have you tried `dir := 'C:\Users\David Heffernan\Desktop';ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'rundll32', PChar('appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere "' + dir + '"'), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)` in Delphi?

Comment: @andreas Why would I want to fire up Delphi for that?  That's O.T.T. I think it wants there to be no quotes to escape the spaces in fact, which seems odd. That's what my experience at Windows|Run tells me. Try `ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'rundll32', PChar('appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere '+dir), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)`.

Comment: @David: I just think it is strange that it works on your Vista 64-bit but not on mine...

Comment: @Andreas Take your quotes out!!

Comment: @Andreas: Shouldn't `'rundll32'` be `PChar`'ed too?

Comment: @David: Yes, `dir := 'C:'` works, but not `dir := 'C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop'`

Comment: @David: It might be a translation issue. I guess you have an English version of Windows. In Swedish, `Desktop` is called `Skrivbord`, but neither of the names works...

Comment: @Andreas: In my Russian Win 7 the folder itself is called 'Desktop' (i.e. in English). The localised name is only displayed by the shell. Anyway, have you been trying this only in Delphi? Does it work e.g. from the command prompt? I mean, using the path parameter that doesn't work in Delphi.

Comment: I have found the problem. For some utterly strange reason, I have managed (programmatically) to rename the "Desktop" folder "OS (C).lnk". Must have happened while doing research for this question... So, since there is no "C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop" folder, of course it doesn't work!

Comment: @Andreas: I suppose it's very fortunate that you've discovered this so soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add an update. At least for Windows 10.

The path supplied to the command needs to target a file that can be converted into a shortcut (.lnk).

Using the example in the answer:

```
rundll32.exe appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere C:\path\to\my\folder
```

Windows will try to change "folder" into a shortcut file (which will fail, because it's a directory not a file).

A working solution is to first create a placeholder file (any extension) and then provide it's path to the command (You can see Windows doing this same sequence if you go New > Shortcut from the context menu: a file called "New shortcut" appears).
Once the dialog is activated and completed, the placeholder file will be renamed and rewritten to be a shortcut file.

Powershell example code:

```
New-Item -Path "C:\temp\New Shortcut.lnk"
rundll32.exe appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere c:\temp\New Shortcut.lnk
```

Two notes:

1. Counter-intuitively, if the path to your placeholder file contains spaces you do not need to encapsulate in quotes. In fact, quotes will cause the command to fail (silently).
   eg: `rundll32.exe appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere "C:\temp\New Text Document.txt"` does nothing, but `rundll32.exe appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere C:\temp\New Text Document.txt` activates the dialog.
2. If you activate and then cancel the shortcut dialog, the placeholder file will be deleted.